# I have deployed a new API on AWS Api-Gateway but when I make a request it says I am not authorised to access it

Tags: reactjs, aws-api-gateway

I am sending a request to another Api belonging to Timetastic which is a service that manages your holidays from work. Here is some of the relevant code in my react app:

```
const token = process.env.TIMETASTIC_TOKEN;
get timetasticAPI() {
    return new Api(token);
}
getPublicHolidays(user) {
    var Model = this.timetasticAPI;
    return Model.get(`timetastic/publicholidays?countryCode=${user.countryCode}`).then(resp => {
        return resp.json();
    })
}
```

This function is then called in another file with the relevant user object passed in. There are other functions which make requests to timetastic which had been made over a year ago and they all work and there is no difference in the javascript so this is not the problem.

On AWS Api-Gateway I have deployed a resource called publicholidays which takes an optional query parameter called countryCode and an authorization header, this is possibly part of the problem as the error is 401 Unauthorised on aws. It is a http api which sends the request to https://app.timetastic.co.uk/api/publicholidays. There are other api's that go to https://app.timetastic.co.uk/api/some-endpoint which all work so I am unsure why this one does not.

The error in my application console is:

Access to fetch at 'https://api.mycompany.co.uk/v1/timetastic/publicholidays?countryCode=GB-EAW' from origin 'https://mycompany.mycompany.co.uk' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Whenever I have had a deployed api not work in the past this has always been the error whatever the issue was so I don't think this is the actual error.

When I make a request to https://app.timetastic.co.uk/api/publicholidays?countryCode=GB-EAW from postman with the bearer token it works and I don't set any headers on there either and I don't know why it works there but not on my app.

When analysing the requests on my app, under request headers for the publicholidays which is not working I have:

authorization: Bearer string-which-is-the-bearer-token

and on the ones which are working I have the following:

access-control-request-headers: authorization
access-control-request-method: GET

Can anybody tell me what is likely wrong or how to work it out? Thanks

Comment: From the error message you have, you need to add the CORS headers to the API in the AWS console. The HTTP API has a very easy implementation to it. Postam doesn't care about the CORS headers.

Comment: I've just enabled Cors thanks but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I just deleted the api and redid it and now it works thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have a pre-flight configured as shown in the image.
2. Add the headers as shown in the image.
3. Redeploy the API
4. Test
   [image]

Comment: I have added this thanks, but it still is not working. I'm still getting the same error and I enabled Cors too.

Comment: I just deleted the api and redid it and now it works thanks